# Use Identity Server for multiple CM instances

Tags: identity-server

We are using Sitecore 9.2 and have several different instances (completely separated with its own deployment for creating different websites).

We want to introduce Azure AD login to use domain login and get two-factor authentication already implemented in Azure. There are different security groups that should give access to the different CM sites.

We expected that we could use one Sitecore Identity Server instance, like this:

[image: Overall diagram]

Hereby we can configure Azure AD identity provider once (and the client create one App Registration in Azure Portal), which would be really great.

How to handle the different access rights per site.
We assumed that we could let identity server do claims transformation to handle the azure group id mapping to some logical names, and then use claims transformation on the actual CM site to map from those logical names to the real sitecore roles.

[image: Authentication sequence]

However, what we experience is that the user is redirected from the identity server callback page to the login page with a message indicating that the user don't have access.

I have tried decompiling the `Sitecore.Plugin.IdentityServer.Controllers.AccountController` to inspect the `ExternalLoginCallback` action method which seems to be the one making redirect to the login page with the `sc_message` querystring. However I don't really see anything related to this, so it must happen somewhere along the Authenticate owin pipeline.

Do anyone know if it is possible to configure/override that validation if the user is allowed to use the system?
Have anyone tried to do something similar?

Thank you for your time!

Comment: I notice that there is an similar but older question related to this: https://sitecore.stackexchange.com/questions/16085/can-the-identity-server-be-used-for-multiple-sites-clients

Comment: We can achieve the above scenario and that is something I have recently implemented. When you get "You dont have access" it is always the claim transformation issue. make sure your are getting the proper ID token and custom claim roles name are properly transferred to Sitecore roles in your claims transformation file on the identity server.

Comment: @JesperBalle can you provide your claim mappings ? seems like you are not assigning correct role as vdivya has mentioned

Answer (score 1):

**Please try doing Claims mappings troubleshooting using ASP.NET 2.0 Membership Tables.**

Appears to be an issue with claim mappings into Identity Server. All the source claims originating from AzureAd are captured and stored in the Core database, within the ExternalUserData table, as shown in the screenshot below:

[image: ExternalUserData]

I have [blogged this recently](https://360agileweb.wordpress.com/2020/02/28/sitecore-host-part-three/), if it is of additional help

Answer (score 0):

We can debug this issue further by creating one dummy user for each sites and assign them desiered sitecore roles. Login to sitecore (without AD) using dummy users with login name and password to see if the sitecore roles created have correct access rights on different sites.

If above use case is working fine then there is only problem with the claim transformation thoes are configured in AD vs Sitecore roles.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry you my late reply here. Thank you very much for you replies.

We evaluated the usage, it is possible to setup the claims correctly.

Our issue was that we wanted to achieve that one user had access to eg. only CM1 instance and another one only to CM2. However Sitecore Identity Server is twisted and tied together with the `core`/membership database. So to achieve this, it is necessary that all CMs share the same membership database (basically the result of the related old answer).
Hereby we need to have all roles on all CMs and make very specific security configuration on content to only allow the required access and basically override built-in access such as Sitecore Client User.

I acknowledge that it is a special case that we want to support multiple CMs but use almost completely different security setup. What we want to achieve can easily be achieved by having an Identity Server pr. CM/Sitecore installation.

Due to some strange hosting restrictions we could not introduce an Identity Server pr. installation so we actually ended up using the older Sitecore Federated Authentication to authenticate to Azure with same `clientId` but have completely different configuration of claims transformation per instance